# Dynamically add a unique button to my stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, button

i was trying out Microsoft blend and i added a button to my stackpanel.

I did the Following:

1)Edit a Copy of the Button Template: Key = "ButtonStyle1".

2)Deleted the Content Presenter.

3)Added an Image Control and linked it up with a image in my desktop.

May i know how do i do this dynamically using c# code behind to add a button and do the following above. Taking into consideration that i already know the path of the image.

Comment: You don't "do stuff" in procedural C# code in WPF. That's what XAML is for. Please reword your question explaining what you really need to do.

Comment: This answer is probably what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5930121/2609288

Comment: But i want to delete the content and add image control. How issit done?