# C#WPF hello world button_click

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I am a beginner , I make my first application.  want to do a hello 'name'.I do this :

```
namespace MyApp
{
  public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
  {
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Title = "Page1";
        Height = 500;
        Width = 500;

        TextBox NameTxtBox = new TextBox();
        NameTxtBox.Width = 300;

        Button Button1 = new Button();
        Button1.Content = "ok";

        TextBlock TxtBlock = new TextBlock();
        TxtBlock.Width = 300;

        StackPanel MyStackPanel = new StackPanel();
        MyStackPanel.Margin = new Thickness(10);
        MyStackPanel.Height = 500;
        MyStackPanel.Width = 500;
        MyStackPanel.Children.Add(NameTxtBox);
        MyStackPanel.Children.Add(ValidateButton);
        MyStackPanel.Children.Add(TxtBlock);

        Content = MyStackPanel;
    }
  }
}
```

in textbox write his name, and when the button is clicked , the text displayed in textblock would hello 'name' (name = name written in textbox).

I can't use privade void button_click (...) in public MainPage(), and after, i don't have access to textblock.text

Comment: [XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059(v=vs.110).aspx) should improve things greately.

Comment: My XAML version work, it is almost only click with the mobile viewer. I would like to run this new version. But thx for this answer

Comment: You should also learn MVVM; WPF works much better that way

Comment: If this is how you intend on approaching WPF, you'll be in a world of pain on your first non-trivial project...

Comment: What is your advice to do what I want to do in a better way ? I just waiting to learn

Comment: Move all that code to XAML, learn the MVVM pattern and use a good MVVM framework...

Answer (score 1):

You need an event handler to handle the click of the button.

The event handler is a function that will be triggered each time the user presses the button.

The handler looks like this:

```
public void Button1_OnClick(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    //Place Code here
}
```

The name of the handler is just a convention, you can name it however you like. Then you need to register this event handler to the appropriate event, in this case to the Button1.OnClick() event.
You can do so in many ways, you can use the properties tab of the Visual Studio IDE or you can simply type the following from within your Main function:

```
Button1.OnClick += Button1_OnClick
```

The above code segment links the handler with the actual event. An event can have multiple handlers.

An event is a list of methods that are called when the event is fired.

For more information check this tutorial from MSDN [Events And Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Currently your "ok" button doesn't do anything.

You can use graphical XAML designer, or if you wish to keep dynamic control adding (like currently), you have to attach an Event Handler on the Click event of your button.

In this event handler, you'll have to write the behavior you want to have when the button will be clicked.

This example will certainly be helpful : http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/5929779/461444