# c# setting the name of a dynamically created button so it can be called later

Tags: c#, wpf, button

how do i set a buttons name when i created it in c# so i can call it later?

i have a a List of strings (Commands).

i loop over it an create a button for each item in the List.

```
       commands.ForEach(delegate (String i)
        {


            Button button = new Button()
            {
                Name = i,
                Tag = i,
                MaxWidth = 50,
                MaxHeight = 50,
                BorderBrush = null
            };


            button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button_Click);
            this.grid.Children.Add(button);

            Uri resourceUri = new Uri("led_Off.png", UriKind.Relative);
            StreamResourceInfo streamInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(resourceUri);

            BitmapFrame temp = BitmapFrame.Create(streamInfo.Stream);
            var brush = new ImageBrush();
            brush.ImageSource = temp;

            button.Background = brush;

        });
```

This loop works fine until i add the line 
`Name = i`

i am in a spot where these buttons were created and i now need to change some of there back ground images. 
is there a better way to call them then by there name?

Comment: Your name should probably be assigned `Name = "button" + i,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name should be a valid string: try `Name = "button" + i.ToString()` (FYI, `Button` `Name` cannot be just "1", it's an invalid Name). Also, `Tag =i.ToString()`. Hope this may help

Comment: Thanks,  that did it!  i have tried to solve this for over two days. i will accept the answer  as soon as i can.

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad it works for you. Please mark the answer accepted if you are satisfied with solution. Good luck with your project. Best regards,

Comment: yes the button name was ment to be "i" not 1 that was a typo on my part. thanks again. great help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it, use [data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [data templating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with [commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead.

There is no reason to ever create any UI elements in a loop in WPF.

Edit: [Just this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5930121/546730)