# Add multiple buttons

Tags: wpf

So I want to add x buttons this value is going to be from a variable that is inputed by the user 
I put like 5 tables and 5 buttons will appear. 
Any help?

Comment: Read a good book? We cannot teach programming, that's way to broad for our format. Do you have a specific question, are you stuck at a specific problem *that you tried to solve yourself first*? Post your best try.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929710/dynamically-add-multiple-buttons-to-wpf-window to see how to dynamically add buttons. ...possible duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want an ItemsControl. It let's you define a template (in your case, a button) and bind to a collection of items like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding MyCollectionOfObjects>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding MyStringProperty}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```