# how to add multiple different controls(ex-TextBox,Button etc) dynamically to the window through xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am having  a set of buttons on window. when I clicked on that buttons I want to add Different controls dynamically.
consider I am having two buttons 
1> AddTextBox
2>AddButton

When I click on AddTextButton the TextBox should be added to window
when I click on AddButton the Button should be added

Comment: *"through xaml"* ? Dynamically usually means programmatically (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7885604/1997232)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you want to dynamically add buttons via binding the following approach may help you.

At first you add a `ItemsControl` section to your xaml defining an ItemTemplate.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DynamicControlObjects}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}"
                     ToolTip="{Binding Tooltip}"
                     IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The `DynamicControlObjects` is just a simple `IList<T>` where `T` is a class containing the properties you want to bind.

For example what I am using in this case is my class `DynamicControlHelper`:

```
// ...

using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.ViewModel;

// ...

public class DynamicControlHelper : NotificationObject
{
    #region Backing Fields

    private string _text;
    private bool _isEnabled;
    private string _tooltip;

    #endregion Backing Fields

    #region Properties

    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return this._text;
        }

        set
        {
            if (!string.Equals(this._text, value))
            {
                this._text = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(this.Text));
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return this._isEnabled;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this._isEnabled != value)
            {
                this._isEnabled = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsEnabled));
            }
        }
    }

    // ...

    public string Tooltip
    {
        get
        {
            return this._tooltip;
        }

        set
        {
            if (!string.Equals(this._tooltip, value))
            {
                this._tooltip = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(this.Tooltip));
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion Properties
}
```

---

When I needed this approach the first time. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5930121/5893316) from [H.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546730/h-b) leads me to my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can add like below code snippet,

```
private void AddButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var rowCount = this.grid.RowDefinitions.Count;
        this.grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });
        var button = new Button() { Content = "Button1", Height = 20, Width = 50 };
        Grid.SetRow(button, rowCount + 1);
        this.grid.Children.Add(button);
    }
```